# Можно ли ускорить загрузку таблицы?

Tags: java, html, datatable

я использую [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) для довольно большой таблицы 1600 строк, и при загрузке, браузер показывает сначала все 1600 строк а потом только загружает ее с помощью DT в том виде в котором она должна быть(как на оф. сайте), и происходит это очень долго, можно ли ускорить это дело или хотя бы не показывать все 1600 строк до того как скрипт их загрузит?
Код вывода:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
  html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"> </script>
    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        <%@include file= "/WEB-INF/js/dataTables.searchBuilder.js"%>
    </script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/searchbuilder/css/searchBuilder.dataTables.css?_=a51bf91506bde26d764a44ddd25768db.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/searchbuilder/css/searchBuilder.dataTables.css?_=a51bf91506bde26d764a44ddd25768db.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Project team list</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <table id="KipTable">
        <thead>
        <tr><th> ID </th><th> Короткое название </th><th>Полное название</th><th>Статус</th><th> Код проекта </th><th> </th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="kip" items="${kip}">
            <tr>
                <td><a href='<c:url value="/kip_edit?id=${kip.id}"/>'>${kip.id}</a></td>
                <td>${kip.shortName}</td>
                <td>${kip.fullName}</td>
                <td>${kip.status}</td>
                <td>${kip.code}</td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action='<c:url value="/kip_delete" />'  style="display:inline;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${kip.id}">
                        <input type="submit"  value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
<script id="rendered-js">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var table = $('#KipTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Qltip',
            stateSave: true
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

на стороне сервера используется Java 6 + Tomcat 7
UPD1: на сайте DT есть функция [ServerSide](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide)(совет из комментария), но я не понимаю что делать с Ajax и как его использовать с сервером на Java, в примерах везде используется PHP который я не знаю

UPD2: добавил код сервлета:

```
public class Kip_list extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ArrayList<Kip_line> kip = Kip_Zaprosy.select();
        req.getSession().setAttribute("kip", kip);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/kip_list.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста с примерами, в интернете очень мало примеров как это делать, и люди используют spring который я не использую

Comment: Конечно можно. Надо сделать [serverside datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/).

Comment: Прежде всего, вы должны добавить [ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Loading-data) параметр в datatable со ссылкой на бек, которая будет возвращать нужные нам данные. Так же, чтобы эти данные возвращались нужно добавить параметр [columns](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Column-data-points), который описывает как отображаются нужные колонки в таблице.

Comment: @indevx там дофига параметров надо передавать.

Comment: @RomanC 4 это много?

Comment: Ну это больше чем 2 @indevx

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать параметры `iDisplayStart` и `iDisplayLength` и, конечно же, свойство `"bServerSide": true` функции `datatable ()`.

Функция Ajax передает некоторые параметры для загрузки данных, которые потом возвращает с сервера и подгружает в таблицу.

Comment: В той версии которая исп-ся сейчас я отправлял все данные сразу на JSP все 1600 строк одним ArrayList, можно как мне поправить мой код чтобы работало правильно? (код я добавил в вопрос)

Comment: Понимаешь, что такое JSP? Зачем туда данные пихать? Если бы вопрос не о том что тормозит загрузка страницы, то я наверное бы не обращал внимание.

Comment: Дело в том что я только-только начал въезжать в веб-разработку(не говоря уже о том что с java я знаком только 2 месяца ), и все в основном делаешь по каким либо примерам, т.к. читая документацию обычно ничерта не понимаешь. Когда гугл ничего не дает, идешь сюда, задаешь вопрос, а люди отвечают так как будто я сходу должен все знать...

Comment: про ajax я вообще молчу, о нем примеры в 95% связанные с PHP, а оставшиеся 5% не то что нужно....

Comment: Нефиг сюда вообще ходить, думаешь что тут тебе все по полочкам распишут? Тут надо самому думать, кому интересно отпишут коментами, остальные просто пройдут мимо.

Comment: Тогда зачем вообще форум нужен если нельзя вопросы задавать?

Comment: Это не форум, тут пишут качественные  вопросы и ответы, созданные по определённым правилам, которые потом будут читать многие.

Comment: По вашему краткие указания будут понятны тому кто только начал все это осваивать?

Comment: Это не указания, а ответ на вопрос, короткий, потому что я на телефоне его набираю, на английском сайте у меня есть более полный ответ. Ты задаешь сразу несколько вопросов, никто тебя не будет тут учить Аяксу или писать сервлеты вместо тебя, учить фреймворки, все надо делать самому.